# KnockoutJs on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, knockout.js

I am trying to use KnockoutJS on Node.js.

Found one implementation of the same here : https://github.com/mtscout6/knockout-node

Has anyone implemented this any other way?

Basically I want the capability to use Computed Observable on Server.

Is it possible to have this feature in javascript using any other library?

Comment: I'm not sure knockout is fit for server-side view rendering. What would you expect to happen when a value in an observable changes? Do you just want to be able to use observables without using them for rendering views?

Comment: You would have to update the observable using Ajax or a node library similar to [NowJS](https://github.com/Flotype/now)

Comment: @badsyntax Yes I want Observables without using them for rendering views. In my application, I have knockout on client side. My ViewModels are dynamic, they are created at runtime using metadata. I inject business logic in the form of Computed Observables in these ViewModels. I want to reuse this on server side, without having Views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hardly recommend you not to use this architecture, because it is less documented and you won't find much support about this over the web. Furthermore KO is intended to work as an client framework. If it is nothing confidential, pass the values and compute client-side?

On Client side it will look like

```
this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
}, this);
```

inside your viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution from knockoutJS mailing list.

There is one node-module which provides exactly same functionality as regards computed observables and subscriptions.

https://npmjs.org/package/obs

"Obs" provides minimalist observable properties.

It is awesome..

Comment: Knockouts dependency tracking is done automatically, no need to define what your computed observable depends on. Obs, on the other hand, needs you to tell it what to subscribe to.